# Oasys Mail Manager alternative

Tags: windows, file-management, email, outlook

Does anyone know good alternatives to Oasys Mail Manager. For those that have not heard of it, it is a outlook plugin that lets you set up a series of filing locations so you can file emails onto your computer or server location. I should stress they are not located in .pst files or containers, they are stored as .msg files. The emails can then be searched as you would search emails files in outlook. As an architect, with many users in the firm, I am able to setup locations for clients, consultants, etc and then anyone in the office can file to these shared locations on the server. It also remembers which recipients are filed where and provides suggestions based on previous filing choices.

There are a lot of good things about the software but I have a couple of issues with the direction of development so wondered if there is anything else out there. I am not interested in setting up outlook rules or plugins that automatically move emails within outlook after receiving them as these are not very smart.

I want a full featured plugin.

Comment: Try [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try eFiler which does the same job only faster, cheaper and easier to use.I think it's got a free trial. Very good search, rules (which Mail Manager doesn't have) and talks directly to cloud and WebDAV services. We used to use Mail Manager but it got too buggy and their support was useless and haven't looked back.